# WordPress (PHP) Posting Timezone Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, time, timezone

Version: PHP 7.3.1

When scheduling a post, there is a 9 hour delay. When commenting or posting, the timestamp immediately shows "9 hours ago."

I want to set 'Asia/Seoul' as the time. I checked the server using phpinfo(), and the server time is correct.
[image: phpinfo() server time]

I also set 'Seoul' for the timezone in the settings.

I used hardcode "date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Seoul')" temporarily, but it is difficult to apply it to every single function. I need a foundational solution for this issue.

I would appreciate if anyone could help me solve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: If you set the good time zone in your wordpress backoffice (Settings > general > Timezone), it should work whatever your server time's settings. The problem maybe related to your theme : check the way the dates are printed in your theme files and share the code with us.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I already tested with different themes including basic themes provided by WordPress. It's not because of themes.

Comment: I fixed this issue by checking each plugin.